# Достать ссылку из JSON Python

Tags: python, json, api, вконтакте

Всем привет, есть такой JSON:

```
{
  "response": {
    "count": 6,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 456239948,
        "album_id": -7,
        "owner_id": 515828454,
        "sizes": [
          {
            "type": "m",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c849120\\/v849120908\\/11ecf2\\/cP63mHO4X7Y.jpg",
            "width": 130,
            "height": 130
          },
          {
            "type": "o",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c849120\\/v849120908\\/11ecf5\\/avoOqJ_Lnq8.jpg",
            "width": 130,
            "height": 130
          },
          {
            "type": "p",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c849120\\/v849120908\\/11ecf6\\/C--Fx3udaP8.jpg",
            "width": 200,
            "height": 200
          },
          {
            "type": "q",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c849120\\/v849120908\\/11ecf7\\/F05L27R9ab8.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 320
          },
          {
            "type": "r",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c849120\\/v849120908\\/11ecf8\\/t9KH4owDd84.jpg",
            "width": 510,
            "height": 510
          },
          {
            "type": "s",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c849120\\/v849120908\\/11ecf1\\/Eb3HXnF9Gzs.jpg",
            "width": 75,
            "height": 75
          },
          {
            "type": "x",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c849120\\/v849120908\\/11ecf3\\/JisZPF2QAjs.jpg",
            "width": 604,
            "height": 604
          },
          {
            "type": "y",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c849120\\/v849120908\\/11ecf4\\/kssSFxkvpFg.jpg",
            "width": 750,
            "height": 750
          }
        ],
        "text": "",
        "date": 1550193986,
        "post_id": 254
      },
      {
        "id": 456239893,
        "album_id": -7,
        "owner_id": 515828454,
        "sizes": [
          {
            "type": "m",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c848736\\/v848736194\\/12e297\\/u_gqtSfSXVw.jpg",
            "width": 130,
            "height": 46
          },
          {
            "type": "o",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c848736\\/v848736194\\/12e29a\\/CQjpI-hzM4I.jpg",
            "width": 130,
            "height": 87
          },
          {
            "type": "p",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c848736\\/v848736194\\/12e29b\\/GvdIgjg6eYU.jpg",
            "width": 200,
            "height": 133
          },
          {
            "type": "q",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c848736\\/v848736194\\/12e29c\\/-krf-X7BRck.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 213
          },
          {
            "type": "r",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c848736\\/v848736194\\/12e29d\\/jxUSmsm-94Q.jpg",
            "width": 510,
            "height": 284
          },
          {
            "type": "s",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c848736\\/v848736194\\/12e296\\/Q6r2ZxoIfAU.jpg",
            "width": 75,
            "height": 27
          },
          {
            "type": "x",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c848736\\/v848736194\\/12e298\\/rqFz6cIrX6E.jpg",
            "width": 604,
            "height": 216
          },
          {
            "type": "y",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c848736\\/v848736194\\/12e299\\/snMjaMVNKpo.jpg",
            "width": 794,
            "height": 284
          }
        ],
        "text": "",
        "date": 1549988778
      },
      {
        "id": 456239799,
        "album_id": -7,
        "owner_id": 515828454,
        "sizes": [
          {
            "type": "m",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845324\\/v845324541\\/19e539\\/_iDiZTxnTbc.jpg",
            "width": 86,
            "height": 130
          },
          {
            "type": "o",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845324\\/v845324541\\/19e53e\\/GngpKqde2Uc.jpg",
            "width": 130,
            "height": 197
          },
          {
            "type": "p",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845324\\/v845324541\\/19e53f\\/IWqIxgj7pbg.jpg",
            "width": 200,
            "height": 304
          },
          {
            "type": "q",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845324\\/v845324541\\/19e540\\/pDm6ATGB9MY.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 485
          },
          {
            "type": "r",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845324\\/v845324541\\/19e541\\/Zo39sxF67-Q.jpg",
            "width": 510,
            "height": 774
          },
          {
            "type": "s",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845324\\/v845324541\\/19e538\\/6LeJ7mW2s74.jpg",
            "width": 50,
            "height": 75
          },
          {
            "type": "w",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845324\\/v845324541\\/19e53d\\/SjenQkw5S_I.jpg",
            "width": 1020,
            "height": 1548
          },
          {
            "type": "x",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845324\\/v845324541\\/19e53a\\/iho-X2sWD_E.jpg",
            "width": 398,
            "height": 604
          },
          {
            "type": "y",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845324\\/v845324541\\/19e53b\\/vDS8yCGelis.jpg",
            "width": 532,
            "height": 807
          },
          {
            "type": "z",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845324\\/v845324541\\/19e53c\\/NsBnEe1u2Xw.jpg",
            "width": 712,
            "height": 1080
          }
        ],
        "text": "",
        "date": 1549653364
      },
      {
        "id": 456239796,
        "album_id": -6,
        "owner_id": 515828454,
        "sizes": [
          {
            "type": "m",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c852224\\/v852224132\\/9e18a\\/3pMkVN4d9E0.jpg",
            "width": 70,
            "height": 130
          },
          {
            "type": "o",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c852224\\/v852224132\\/9e18d\\/UwHAP-zZqyg.jpg",
            "width": 130,
            "height": 242
          },
          {
            "type": "p",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c852224\\/v852224132\\/9e18e\\/cJLgLEkC05Q.jpg",
            "width": 200,
            "height": 372
          },
          {
            "type": "q",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c852224\\/v852224132\\/9e18f\\/8xpeGAc1AVw.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 595
          },
          {
            "type": "r",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c852224\\/v852224132\\/9e190\\/uSc63nTRY8k.jpg",
            "width": 344,
            "height": 640
          },
          {
            "type": "s",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c852224\\/v852224132\\/9e189\\/pIwwCScUgME.jpg",
            "width": 40,
            "height": 75
          },
          {
            "type": "x",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c852224\\/v852224132\\/9e18b\\/C-5UjsPUBcs.jpg",
            "width": 325,
            "height": 604
          },
          {
            "type": "y",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c852224\\/v852224132\\/9e18c\\/oJy1NDAWRJQ.jpg",
            "width": 344,
            "height": 640
          }
        ],
        "text": "",
        "date": 1549312914,
        "post_id": 229
      },
      {
        "id": 456239784,
        "album_id": -7,
        "owner_id": 515828454,
        "sizes": [
          {
            "type": "m",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845122\\/v845122589\\/197fe2\\/QL0L6F0QOUo.jpg",
            "width": 130,
            "height": 73
          },
          {
            "type": "o",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845122\\/v845122589\\/197fe6\\/9hLFMdXVWPQ.jpg",
            "width": 130,
            "height": 87
          },
          {
            "type": "p",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845122\\/v845122589\\/197fe7\\/6fuewQpKhyI.jpg",
            "width": 200,
            "height": 133
          },
          {
            "type": "q",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845122\\/v845122589\\/197fe8\\/zkr741APtss.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 213
          },
          {
            "type": "r",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845122\\/v845122589\\/197fe9\\/OGnlHQu0s0Y.jpg",
            "width": 510,
            "height": 340
          },
          {
            "type": "s",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845122\\/v845122589\\/197fe1\\/t1Yt_Eo7Srg.jpg",
            "width": 75,
            "height": 42
          },
          {
            "type": "x",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845122\\/v845122589\\/197fe3\\/xk1U8uYO7bM.jpg",
            "width": 604,
            "height": 340
          },
          {
            "type": "y",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845122\\/v845122589\\/197fe4\\/0zlCZg8_GIE.jpg",
            "width": 807,
            "height": 454
          },
          {
            "type": "z",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c845122\\/v845122589\\/197fe5\\/K1I1N7ag1E8.jpg",
            "width": 1080,
            "height": 607
          }
        ],
        "text": "",
        "date": 1549254714
      },
      {
        "id": 456239783,
        "album_id": -6,
        "owner_id": 515828454,
        "sizes": [
          {
            "type": "m",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c850436\\/v850436157\\/aaf15\\/6SXBo_fhTeg.jpg",
            "width": 130,
            "height": 130
          },
          {
            "type": "o",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c850436\\/v850436157\\/aaf18\\/kYyN0CtNF7A.jpg",
            "width": 130,
            "height": 130
          },
          {
            "type": "p",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c850436\\/v850436157\\/aaf19\\/XruYClB7GwA.jpg",
            "width": 200,
            "height": 200
          },
          {
            "type": "q",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c850436\\/v850436157\\/aaf1a\\/QpcMV2ZmVCk.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 320
          },
          {
            "type": "r",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c850436\\/v850436157\\/aaf1b\\/nPSh398CfLU.jpg",
            "width": 510,
            "height": 510
          },
          {
            "type": "s",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c850436\\/v850436157\\/aaf14\\/M-LUawivBmM.jpg",
            "width": 75,
            "height": 75
          },
          {
            "type": "x",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c850436\\/v850436157\\/aaf16\\/oEA7zh7PyZ0.jpg",
            "width": 604,
            "height": 604
          },
          {
            "type": "y",
            "url": "https:\\/\\/pp.userapi.com\\/c850436\\/v850436157\\/aaf17\\/ES82Gsu4XtU.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 640
          }
        ],
        "text": "",
        "date": 1549222235,
        "post_id": 217
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Как из него достать ссылки на фотографии максимального размера?

Answer (score 4):

Принцип такой же как в ответе @Sergey Gornostaev, но я использовал `max()` вместо `sorted()`:

```
hrefs = [(max(i['sizes'], key=lambda x: x['width'] * x['height'])
          ['url'].replace('\\',''))
         for i in d['response']['items']]
```

результат:

```
In [36]: hrefs
Out[36]:
['https://pp.userapi.com/c849120/v849120908/11ecf4/kssSFxkvpFg.jpg',
 'https://pp.userapi.com/c848736/v848736194/12e299/snMjaMVNKpo.jpg',
 'https://pp.userapi.com/c845324/v845324541/19e53d/SjenQkw5S_I.jpg',
 'https://pp.userapi.com/c852224/v852224132/9e190/uSc63nTRY8k.jpg',
 'https://pp.userapi.com/c845122/v845122589/197fe5/K1I1N7ag1E8.jpg',
 'https://pp.userapi.com/c850436/v850436157/aaf17/ES82Gsu4XtU.jpg']
```

Comment: И правда так лучше, я что-то тупанул спросонья.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def extract(album):
    url = sorted(album['sizes'], key=lambda x: x['height']*x['width'])[-1]['url']
    return re.sub(r'\\+', '', url)

hrefs = [extract(i) for i in d['response']['items'] if len(i.get('sizes', []))]
```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью непосредственно питона это делать ужасно неудобно. Для этого специально была сделана утилита [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Она создана для преобразования одного json (большого и неудобного) в другой json (маленький и вкусный). jq обладает мощным синтаксисом и много чего умеет. Давайте рассмотрим Ваш пример.

```
.response.items[] | .sizes | [.[] | {"url": .url, "width": .width, "height": .height}]
```

Вот что мы получим:

```
[{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c849120/v849120908/11ecf2/cP63mHO4X7Y.jpg","width":130,"height":130},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c849120/v849120908/11ecf5/avoOqJ_Lnq8.jpg","width":130,"height":130},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c849120/v849120908/11ecf6/C--Fx3udaP8.jpg","width":200,"height":200},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c849120/v849120908/11ecf7/F05L27R9ab8.jpg","width":320,"height":320},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c849120/v849120908/11ecf8/t9KH4owDd84.jpg","width":510,"height":510},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c849120/v849120908/11ecf1/Eb3HXnF9Gzs.jpg","width":75,"height":75},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c849120/v849120908/11ecf3/JisZPF2QAjs.jpg","width":604,"height":604},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c849120/v849120908/11ecf4/kssSFxkvpFg.jpg","width":750,"height":750}]
[{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c848736/v848736194/12e297/u_gqtSfSXVw.jpg","width":130,"height":46},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c848736/v848736194/12e29a/CQjpI-hzM4I.jpg","width":130,"height":87},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c848736/v848736194/12e29b/GvdIgjg6eYU.jpg","width":200,"height":133},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c848736/v848736194/12e29c/-krf-X7BRck.jpg","width":320,"height":213},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c848736/v848736194/12e29d/jxUSmsm-94Q.jpg","width":510,"height":284},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c848736/v848736194/12e296/Q6r2ZxoIfAU.jpg","width":75,"height":27},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c848736/v848736194/12e298/rqFz6cIrX6E.jpg","width":604,"height":216},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c848736/v848736194/12e299/snMjaMVNKpo.jpg","width":794,"height":284}]
[{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845324/v845324541/19e539/_iDiZTxnTbc.jpg","width":86,"height":130},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845324/v845324541/19e53e/GngpKqde2Uc.jpg","width":130,"height":197},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845324/v845324541/19e53f/IWqIxgj7pbg.jpg","width":200,"height":304},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845324/v845324541/19e540/pDm6ATGB9MY.jpg","width":320,"height":485},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845324/v845324541/19e541/Zo39sxF67-Q.jpg","width":510,"height":774},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845324/v845324541/19e538/6LeJ7mW2s74.jpg","width":50,"height":75},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845324/v845324541/19e53d/SjenQkw5S_I.jpg","width":1020,"height":1548},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845324/v845324541/19e53a/iho-X2sWD_E.jpg","width":398,"height":604},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845324/v845324541/19e53b/vDS8yCGelis.jpg","width":532,"height":807},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845324/v845324541/19e53c/NsBnEe1u2Xw.jpg","width":712,"height":1080}]
[{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c852224/v852224132/9e18a/3pMkVN4d9E0.jpg","width":70,"height":130},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c852224/v852224132/9e18d/UwHAP-zZqyg.jpg","width":130,"height":242},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c852224/v852224132/9e18e/cJLgLEkC05Q.jpg","width":200,"height":372},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c852224/v852224132/9e18f/8xpeGAc1AVw.jpg","width":320,"height":595},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c852224/v852224132/9e190/uSc63nTRY8k.jpg","width":344,"height":640},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c852224/v852224132/9e189/pIwwCScUgME.jpg","width":40,"height":75},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c852224/v852224132/9e18b/C-5UjsPUBcs.jpg","width":325,"height":604},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c852224/v852224132/9e18c/oJy1NDAWRJQ.jpg","width":344,"height":640}]
[{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845122/v845122589/197fe2/QL0L6F0QOUo.jpg","width":130,"height":73},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845122/v845122589/197fe6/9hLFMdXVWPQ.jpg","width":130,"height":87},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845122/v845122589/197fe7/6fuewQpKhyI.jpg","width":200,"height":133},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845122/v845122589/197fe8/zkr741APtss.jpg","width":320,"height":213},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845122/v845122589/197fe9/OGnlHQu0s0Y.jpg","width":510,"height":340},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845122/v845122589/197fe1/t1Yt_Eo7Srg.jpg","width":75,"height":42},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845122/v845122589/197fe3/xk1U8uYO7bM.jpg","width":604,"height":340},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845122/v845122589/197fe4/0zlCZg8_GIE.jpg","width":807,"height":454},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c845122/v845122589/197fe5/K1I1N7ag1E8.jpg","width":1080,"height":607}]
[{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c850436/v850436157/aaf15/6SXBo_fhTeg.jpg","width":130,"height":130},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c850436/v850436157/aaf18/kYyN0CtNF7A.jpg","width":130,"height":130},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c850436/v850436157/aaf19/XruYClB7GwA.jpg","width":200,"height":200},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c850436/v850436157/aaf1a/QpcMV2ZmVCk.jpg","width":320,"height":320},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c850436/v850436157/aaf1b/nPSh398CfLU.jpg","width":510,"height":510},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c850436/v850436157/aaf14/M-LUawivBmM.jpg","width":75,"height":75},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c850436/v850436157/aaf16/oEA7zh7PyZ0.jpg","width":604,"height":604},{"url":"https://pp.userapi.com/c850436/v850436157/aaf17/ES82Gsu4XtU.jpg","width":640,"height":640}]
```

Но как Вы моги видеть, указанный выше скрипт фильтрует json до нужной структуры. Для того, чтобы выбрать максимальные по размеру изображения, его нужно немного модифицировать:

```
.response.items[] | .sizes | [.[] | {"url": .url, "area": (.width * .height)}] | max_by(.area)
```

Вот такой результат мы получим:

```
{
  "url": "https://pp.userapi.com/c849120/v849120908/11ecf4/kssSFxkvpFg.jpg",
  "area": 562500
}
{
  "url": "https://pp.userapi.com/c848736/v848736194/12e299/snMjaMVNKpo.jpg",
  "area": 225496
}
{
  "url": "https://pp.userapi.com/c845324/v845324541/19e53d/SjenQkw5S_I.jpg",
  "area": 1578960
}
{
  "url": "https://pp.userapi.com/c852224/v852224132/9e18c/oJy1NDAWRJQ.jpg",
  "area": 220160
}
{
  "url": "https://pp.userapi.com/c845122/v845122589/197fe5/K1I1N7ag1E8.jpg",
  "area": 655560
}
{
  "url": "https://pp.userapi.com/c850436/v850436157/aaf17/ES82Gsu4XtU.jpg",
  "area": 409600
}
```

то есть мы добавили выбор по максимальной площади для каждой группы. Вообще говоря, эту логику лучше было бы реализовать на python, но коль скоро вопрос звучит: как выбрать максимальное по объёму изображение. Ответ выше.

Разберём его начало. **jq** работает как пайплайн, т.е. перебирает элементы друг за другом и передаёт на следующий этап обработки. Давайте построим нашу конструкцию итеративно:

```
.response
```

Данная конструкция вытащит то, что содержит поле `response`. Я не буду приводить результат. Попробуйте сами в онлайн редакторе.

```
.response.items[]
```

Далее, мы говорим **jq** вытащить все элементы списка.

.response.items[] | .sizes

Теперь каждый элемент списка передаём в пайплайн и из каждого вытаскиваем `.sizes`. И так далее.

Я советую поиграться с ним для того, чтобы понять, как он работает. У jq очень хорошая дока и это прямо must have для разраба. Есть минус. Не очень удобный синтаксис к которому привыкаешь довольно быстро при частом использовании.

Я, например, регулярно использую это утилиту для того, чтобы распарсить json, который получаю от какого-нибудь API. Это намного удобнее, чем использовать python или другой язык.

Чем это лучше стандартного подхода, который часто приводят люди с использованием python и perl? Во-первых, Вы не пишете код. Во-вторых, эти скрипты можно выносить в отдельные файлы и сохранять где-нибудь отдельно, загружая при необходимости. Вы избавляете человека, который будет читать Ваш код (в т.ч. себя) от необходимости разбираться в сложных цикла (см. другие ответы) парсинга json. В данном конкретном случае, циклы не слишком противные. Но и json здесь не слишком громоздкий. Взамен получаете скрипт jq, который инкапсулирует от Вас всю внутреннюю кухню парсинга и читается проще.

Кстати, говоря, у jq есть [интерпретатор онлайн](https://jqplay.org/). Для удобства, я сначала отредактировал это сообщение в [json-lint](https://jsonlint.com/). Кроме того, я очень советую не избегать многих консольных утилит и активно их использовать, вместо python и его аналогов для бытовых нужд:

- `grep`
- `sort`
- `sed`
- `jq`
- ...

Данная утилита итегрируется в питон очень [просто](https://pypi.org/project/pyjq/). Пример из доки:

```
import pyjq
value = {"user":"stedolan","titles":["JQ Primer", "More JQ"]}
jq_script = '{user, title: .titles[]}'  # Можно и нужно загружать из файла
x = pyjq.all(jq_script, value)
print(x)
```

> [{'user': 'stedolan', 'title': 'JQ Primer'}, {'user': 'stedolan', 'title': 'More JQ'}]

Важно, в jq на питоне требуется передавать словарь. Поэтому, если Вы читали данные из файла json, то вам потребуется десериализация