# Парсинг большого xml файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Использую `xml.ETree.ElementTree` для парсинга большого xml файла последовательно с помощью iterparse. Однако со временем приложение начинает съедать много памяти. Похоже, хоть iterparse и обрабатывает документ последовательно, но сохраняет всё дерево документа. Как этого избежать?

Желательно с помощью стандартной библиотеки, а не сторонних парсеров.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Есть замечательная утилита [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Она используется для парсинга json. Есть аналоги для xml. Советую Вам посмотреть в сторону [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `xml.parsers.expat`, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/814723ddaf3782ce27f5ba62820db6d65af77f49/xml.parsers.expat__examples__like_sax/hello_world.py Но это очень низкий уровень, зато позволит эффективно обрабатываь гигантские xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замечательная утилита [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Она используется для парсинга json. Есть аналоги для xml. Советую Вам посмотреть в сторону [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)

Взгляните на мой ответ [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/945716/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-json-python/945748#945748). Он описывает работу с jq

Стандартные парсеры (а-ля `xml.ETree`) плохи тем, что, как правило, они медленные и накладые, как Вы заметили по памяти. Кроме того, они размазывают парсинг по коду и он становится плохо читаемым и неподдерживаемым. jq и аналоги позволяют локализовать проблему в отдельном скрипте, а сценарий парсинга читать на порядке удобнее.

Answer (score 1):

В статье: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-hiperfparse/index.html рассказывается, что iterparse для оптимизации сохраняет много разных ссылок, которые хорошо бы подчищать.

Пример из статьи:

```
def fast_iter(context, func):
    for event, elem in context:
        func(elem)
        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]
    del context

def write_title(elem):
    out.write('%s\n' % elem.text.encode('utf-8'))

context = etree.iterparse(infile, events=('end',), tag='Title')
fast_iter(context, write_title)
```